# Unable to change permissions for a folder

Tags: 18.04, permissions

The folder permissions says
*"You are not the owner, so you cannot change these permissions"*

I have ran

```
sudo find /opt/popcorntime -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

But the result is

> chmod: changing permissions of
>   '/opt/popcorntime/src/app/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.woff': Operation not
>   permitted.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Have you looked to see the current ownership and permissions of `/opt/popcorntime/src/app/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.woff` ?

Comment: Read the error `you are not the **owner**` `man chown`

Answer (score 0):

Something may be wrong with directories
Try this:

```
sudo find /opt/popcorntime -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
sudo find /opt/popcorntime -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```